# Redis Cache expiration

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, ioredis

I've been encountering this problem with ioredis where I have created a key and set expiry for that key. My code looks something like this

```
let temp1 = acct.limit;
let txn = array.length;
let cache = new ioredis(); // note that this is not the exact code snippet
let ttl = txn / temp1;
cache.set('key', true, Math.ceil(ttl));
```

The problem that I encountered is that sometimes the `ttl` is a positive number and sometimes a negative number. Thus, leading to the belief that maybe -1 is for an unlimited ttl. But upon further research and also trial and error anything less than or equal to 0 expires immediately. So my question really is, why some keys don't expire even with a set ttl?

Answer (score 0):

Redis EXPIRE for a key is set in ttl seconds. So anything less than or equal to 0 for the ttl value will expire the keys immediately. The question is not clear because you have already explained that anything less than or equal to 0 will make the key expire immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`TTL` command returns three types of [responses](https://redis.io/commands/ttl);

- Returns the remaining time to live of a key that has a timeout in seconds.
- Returns -2 if the key does not exist.
- Returns -1 if the key exists but has no associated expire.